# Need help fixing this .json file

Tags: json

```
{
    "bridge": {
        "username": "CC:22:33:E3:CE:30",
        "name": "Homebridge",
        "pin": "987-65-432"
    },

    "platforms": [{
        "platform": "Nest",
        "username": “tommycrosby@att.net”,
        "password": ”Crosby123456!”
    }]
}
```

It says i need to double quote the username and password but i tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have `“` instead of the expected `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use " instead of “. You can use a parser to check your json style in the future like http://json.parser.online.fr/.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong Quote-Symbol. Here is the fixed JSON:

```
{
    "bridge": {
        "username": "CC:22:33:E3:CE:30",
        "name": "Homebridge",
        "pin": "987-65-432"
    },

    "platforms": [{
        "platform": "Nest",
        "username": "tommycrosby@att.net",
        "password": "Crosby123456!"
    }]
}
```

The one you were using is `”` (right double quotation mark). But you need to use `"` (quotation mark) instead.